# SignalR upgrade from 3.1.5 to 6.0.11 in Angular causing navigation issues to 'result' component

Tags: angular, service, signalr, angular2-routing

I have a Microsoft SignalR service in my Angular project. Everything was working fine with SignalR version 3.1.5. However, after updating to version 6.0.11, I'm facing a peculiar issue. When a user scans a QR code, the URL in the browser changes, and it's expected to navigate the user to the 'result' component. Unfortunately, this navigation isn't happening even though the URL changes. I've double-checked my router setup, and it seems to be correct.

Here's the relevant part of my SignalR service where I handle the navigation:

```
this._hubConnection.on('PaymentCompleted', (statusData) => {
   if (statusData && statusData.skipInfoMessage) {
     window.location.href = statusData.redirectUrl;
   }else {
     if (statusData && statusData.success) {
        this.router.navigate(['result'], { queryParams: { status: true } });
     }else {
        this.router.navigate(['result'], { queryParams: { status: false } });
     }
   }
   this._hubConnection.stop().finally();
   this._hubConnection = null;
});
```

From my **app-routing.module.ts**:

```
{
   path: 'result',
   component: ResultComponent
}
```

Upon upgrading SignalR, I encountered two errors when running my Angular project using npm start:

1. An issue with finally() in the SignalR service.
2. A node-related issue (I don't recall the exact error message).

To address these errors:

- I added **es2018.promise** to the lib in tsconfig.json.
- In **tsconfig.app.json**, under **compilerOptions**, I added '**node**' to the types array.

Here's my **package.json** for reference:

```
{

   "name": "angulartemplate",

   "version": "0.0.0",

   "scripts": {

     "test": "jest --config ./src/jest.config.js",

     "ng": "ng",

     "start": "ng serve --port 4201 --public-host \"http://localhost:8811/Pay\"",

     "build": "ng build",

     "release": "ng build --prod",

     "build:ssr": "ng run AngularTemplate:server:dev",

     "lint": "ng lint",

     "e2e": "ng e2e",

     "extract-translations": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src --output 
 ./src/assets/i18n/*.json --clean --sort --format namespaced-json --marker _"

   },

   "private": true,

   "dependencies": {

     "@angular/animations": "^9.1.1",

     "@angular/common": "^9.1.1",

     "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.1",

     "@angular/core": "^9.1.1",

     "@angular/forms": "^9.1.1",

     "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.1",

     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.1",

     "@angular/platform-server": "^9.1.1",

     "@angular/router": "^9.1.1",

     "@angular/service-worker": "^9.1.1",

     "@microsoft/signalr": "^6.0.11",

     "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.2.6",

     "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",

     "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",

     "angular2-qrcode": "^2.0.3",

     "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",

     "core-js": "^3.6.5",

     "oidc-client": "^1.10.1",

     "rxjs": "^6.5.5",

     "zone.js": "^0.10.3"

   },

   "devDependencies": {

     "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.901.9",

     "@angular/cli": "9.1.13",

     "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.1.1",

     "@angular/language-service": "9.1.1",

     "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "7.0.3",

     "@ngneat/spectator": "^5.9.0",

     "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",

     "@types/node": "^13.11.1",

     "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",

     "jasmine-core": "^4.1.1",

     "jest": "^26.0.1",

     "jest-preset-angular": "^8.2.0",

     "karma": "^6.3.19",

     "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",

     "karma-jasmine": "^5.0.1",

     "ng-mocks": "^10.2.1",

     "typescript": "3.7.5"

   },

   "optionalDependencies": {

     "protractor": "~5.4.3",

     "ts-node": "~8.8.2",

     "tslint": "^6.1.1"

   }

 }
```

Additionally, my backend is built using .NET 6.

Apart from the above changes, I haven't made any other modifications to the project. I'm unsure what's causing the navigation issue post the SignalR upgrade. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.